# Getting base GIS files for use with pgRouting library

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, basemap, osm2pgrouting

I'm just starting to read the tutorial for [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/) and the first issue that troubles me is the origin of the "base map" to feed pgRouting with. I'm aware that there's available a tool called [osm2pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting), which converts [OpenStreetMaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) data into pgRouting compatible ones. But I'm not sure if it is the correct/best source for this info, although it clearly might be a starting point and is fairly easy to get it.

What are the other possible source options for this purpose?

I work in an [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vehicle_location) company so, we gather second by second lots of GPS data from vehicles, which we don't actually process to "connect the dots" and turn them into streets, but I'm not sure if this actually helps or not.

Data needed for this project would be for Chile and, as starting point only for the city of Santiago.

Comment: what type of routing will you be doing? osm2pgrouting gets you up and running with pgRouting very quickly and accurately...

Comment: I don't know the exact algorithm we'll be using yet, but we need to compute the best route for pickup and "delivery" of passengers. On a broader goal, those routes must be "weighted" with different passengers and distributed in several vehicles, to achieve the most cost-effective planning possible.

Comment: All that is possible using OSM with pgRouting, but applying weights to the OSM data might be your biggest hurdle. Otherwise, the pgRouting tutorials describe how to prepare your own data for use in pgRouting: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.2.10/en/chapters/topology.html

Comment: I guess weight might come from a mean speed in a specified window time from our own data and, thanks for the link!

Comment: Let us  know if you have any more questions or issues...!